# How to represent a funnel in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to represent a "funnel" in PostgreSQL.

I have an external set of data (represented as numbers here for simplicity but these are items in real world). My Table A should store a subset of the external data, my Table B should store a subset of the subset of the Table A and same story for Table C.

```
External data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Table A:             [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Table B:                [5, 6, 7, 9]
Table C:                   [6, 9]
```

And ideally, if I remove `6` from Table A, I would like to delete it from Table B and C.

How do I represent this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: How about storing the items in a single table and adding a `depth` column?

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreign key constraint from each table to the next higher one that is defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.